# Why does my Eloquent model observer resolve config variables as null using Laravel Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a model observer which has a `deleting` method to observe when a model is deleted. In that observer, I call a method that logs a config variable `logger()->debug(config('queue.connections.members-queue.region'));`. The config variable resolves to `null`. However, when the same code is called from an event (using ShouldQueue, queue driver Sync), it resolves the config variable successfully. The model observer can read the env variable using the `env(...)` method, but not the config variable that resolves the environment variable.

I am using Laravel Lumen, and I have cleared the application cache and restarted the Homestead vagrant box but it is still happening.

Why would a model observer not be able to resolve a config variable?

In my composer.lock I am using `laravel/lumen-framework v5.8.13`.

ETA: Even after clearing out everything in my storage/framework/cache/data/ folder, it is still happening.

Comment: Have you refreshed your config? `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: This is with laravel-lumen so that is not a command. Is there another way to do it with lumen?

Comment: Do you have configuration loaded in your bootstrap file? For example, `$app->configure('cache');` in my application bootstrap/app.php.

Comment: Oh, that seemed to be it. For some reason I was usually able to access the config variables without registering that configuration file, but within the observer it wasn't.